# Are function prototypes going away in Ember 2?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Since the latest Ember release at http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/13/ember-1-12-released.html it seems there is a new syntax for setter and getter methods.

Should we be getting used to doing:

```
fullName: Ember.computed('firstName', 'lastName', function() {
  return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
})
```

Instead of:

```
fullName: function() {
  return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
}.property('firstName', 'lastName')
```

Comment: I'm not sure either.  The first syntax should be used in ember-cli addons as it can't be sure the client has prototype extensions enabled.  There is definitely a new annotation based syntax coming soon though but it is hard to find any details on it. The `Ember.computed` syntax would at least ensure compatibility if it is removed.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: No, wait for the decorators to land in Ember and then switch.

Longer answer:
The `function() { }.property()` way of declaring computed properties depends on extending the function prototype. Extending prototypes of JavaScript 'primitives' is sometimes seen as a bad practice.

The `Ember.computed(function() { })` way is the same as the former, except now the prototype extension is not used.

There is an ongoing discussion on which way is better on the Ember.js github. You can find it [here](https://github.com/emberjs/guides/pull/110).

Also in the near future another, much cleaner, way of declaring computed properties using decorators, should come to Ember. Then computed properties will look like this:`@computed foo() { }`. These are also mentioned in the blog post you link to. You can find more details on these [here](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-computed-decorators).

My opinion is that you should wait for the decorators and then make the switch.